# Get the selected data displayed when radio button selected [ionic]

Tags: radio-button, ionic3, angular5

I'm trying to display the radio button data based on user select but it doesn't display anything. Here is my code :

```
<div ng-app="" ng-init="categoryID">
    <ion-list radio-group>

        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Category 1</ion-label>
            <ion-radio value="category1" ng-model="categoryID"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Category 2</ion-label>
            <ion-radio value="category2" ng-model="categoryID"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Category 3</ion-label>
            <ion-radio value="category3" ng-model="categoryID"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>

    </ion-list>

    <p>Category : {{ categoryID }}</p>
</div>
```

Trying to display like how it display at this url https://codepen.io/terrer-sandman/pen/erMzzQ

Comment: the angular version seems to be angularjs not 5 and also the codepen is printing the category for me..

Comment: @SurajRao Thank you for the reply. Yeah I wanted to print the category like how it be done in the codepen. So you mean that my ionic angular is different from the angular that been used in that codepen?

Comment: Oh I understand it now. I didn't know that AngularJs and Angular are different. I just started to learn the Ionic so I didn't know much about the Angular.